# Retrieving process ID in controller from model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made a file converter using FFmpeg in MVC, and am now trying to cancel a specific conversion process. I get the ID of the process in my Encoder class and try to retrieve it in the FileController. This, however, only gives 0. What is wrong, and how can I retrieve the ID in the controller?

**UPDATED:**
The convert method in FileController is called by two buttons in the view, one for conversion (hidden and starts automatically) and one for cancel. I tried to save the encoder object in a session in Global.asax and then retrieve them again for the conversion and the cancel. This works, but as I added the session, when I try to cancel the process by clicking the button, nothing happens until the convert method is all done. It then starts again (as if it has been in a queue) and goes to the cancel method. Previously to the session, the cancel button would interupt the method.

What can I do to make the cancel button interupt the conversion method?

```
    //Encoder class
    private string RunProcess(string Parameters, string fileType) {
    //...
    ProcessStartInfo oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(this.FFmpegPath, Parameters);
    Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(oInfo);
    _ID = proc.Id;
    //... }

    private int _ID;
    public int Id {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
    }
```

.

```
    //FileController

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Convert(String id, string convert, string kill, string test) {
    //...
    Encoder obj = Session["Encoder"] as Encoder;
    if (convert != null) {
    EncodedVideo encoded = obj.EncodeVideo(inputv, 
    QuickVideoEncodingCommands.Mpeg, outputVPath, true, ext); //Starts encoding
    //...
    } else {
    return KillProcess();
    }}

    public ActionResult KillProcess() {
    Encoder obj = Session["Encoder"] as Encoder;
    int id = obj.Id;
    Process p = Process.GetProcessById(id);
    p.Kill();
    //... }
```

.

```
    //Global.asax
    protected void Session_Start() {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Encoder"] = new Encoder();
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste `Encoder` and `Controller` classes separately. And more code of `Encoder` class would be great.

Comment: Added more info and updated question. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It's a httppost method,it can't get the public variable which changed value before page load.
You should put it in `Model` and send it to `Convert` Method from View.Or try to put it in `Session` or `TempData`,if so,be careful of the concurrent situation.

Comment: I have tried to use a session variable in Global.asax now. It works, but I now have a different problem. The cancel button does not interupt the conversion method as it did before. The question is edited accordingly. Any idea why it happens, and how I can solve it?